# Kubuntu Screensaver create multiple process and after close , all of theme doesn't close

Tags: kubuntu, kde, 13.10, screensaver

Kubuntu Screensaver create multiple process and after screensaver close , all of theme doesn't close.

kcometen4.kss is name of processes.

One time in login , Screensaver open in multiple window! like normal windows in kde.

How can i solve this problem.

i Have kubuntu 13.10

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Kubuntu forums: http://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?63503-kblankscrn-kss

Comment: thanks.But this problem on login because of the screensaver processes is open when shotdown. .kss process must be one and close by closing screensaver. My problem is this processes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bug has been filed in this regard:

- https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=314859

I've got the same behaviour with multiple `keuphoria.kss` windows after login (varying from 1 to 7+ windows).